# How to create netcdfFile without location ? JAVA

Tags: java, netcdf, unidata, netcdf-java

I am trying to convert a product into netcdf object.
i am using unidata library.

What i want to do is return a netcdf object into xml response.

In fact, I create `NetcdfFileWriter` with method

> createNew()

. But a location is mandatory. I do not want to save the file somewhere because what i want is return it into xml response.

My method is now returning `NetcdfFile` created with the method above. But i still have a file on my disk that i do not want.

Have you an idea ?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to create a `NetcdfFile` object in memory with the netCDF-Java library, because there's no in-memory implementation of the underlying `RandomAccessFile`.
You could use a temp file as the location, e.g. `java.io.File.createTempFile()`.

Comment: Thank you, but it seems that the method `NetcdfFileWriter.createNew(Version version, String location)` does not take File as parameter. How can I do ?